# Nestjs CQRS - CommandHandlerNotFoundException

Tags: node.js, cqrs, nestjs

I am trying to use events in my nestjs app.

However when I attempt to trigger command, I get `CommandHandlerNotFoundException`.

I have `message-bus.module`:

```
@Module({
    imports: [CqrsModule],
    providers: [
        MessageBusLocalService,
        StartWorkflowHandler
    ],
    exports: [MessageBusLocalService]
})
export class MessageBusModule {
}
```

`message-bus-local.service`

```
@Injectable()
export class MessageBusLocalService {

    constructor(private readonly commandBus: CommandBus, private eb: EventBus) {
    }

    startWorkflow(workflowId: string, payload: any) {
        return this.commandBus.execute(
            new StartWorkflowCommand(workflowId, payload)
        );
    }
}
```

and `start-workflow.handler`

```
@CommandHandler(StartWorkflowCommand)
export class StartWorkflowHandler implements ICommandHandler<StartWorkflowCommand> {
    constructor() {}

    async execute(command: StartWorkflowCommand) {
        console.log('Workflow started', command.jobId);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am trying to trigger command when app is bootstrapped:

```
    const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);

    const service = app.get(MessageBusLocalService);
    try {
        const c = await service.startWorkflow('abcde', {just: "test"});
        console.log('And returned', c);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
```

and... I get the `CommandHandlerNotFoundException` there although I believe it is declared... What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to use the handler in another module (e.g. `appModule` ) you need to add the `@Injectable()` decorator to the `StartWorkflowHandler` class.

And call `app.init()` in the main.ts. Before starting the application.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MessageBusModule` does not re-export handlers, thus they are not "visible" on app.module level (at least this is what I understand on my own)

I got similar scenario like that:

```
const commands = [NewOrder, ChargeForOrder]
const events = [ChargeOrder, OrderProcessed]
const sagas = [AdjustWalletFunds]

@Module({
  imports: [
    CqrsModule,
    WalletsModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([...]),
  ],
  providers: [...commands, ...events, ...sagas],
  exports: [CqrsModule, ...commands, ...events, ...sagas],
})
export class RxModule {}
```

so, assuming you import your `MessageBusModule` in the main app.module, try the following:

```
@Module({
    imports: [CqrsModule],
    providers: [
        MessageBusLocalService,
        StartWorkflowHandler
    ],
    exports: [MessageBusLocalService, StartWorkflowHandler]
})
export class MessageBusModule {
}
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this did not help.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the method I used in the question does not work.

However it does work as expected if I inject the `MessageBusLocalService` in controller.

It seems odd to answer my own question but it might help someone eventually.

Comment: The commands, events, queries are registering on Init Module events, so may be at the time you call to resolve the command handler, the handler is not ready yet

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you imported have `CqrsModule` imported. Also import the `MessageBusModule` into any other module where it is called from.